# Rows data populated but data not rendered in MUI Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

Here working sample code which i copied from MUI webpages

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    username: '@MUI',
    age: 38,
    desk: 'D-546',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    username: '@MUI-X',
    age: 25,
    desk: 'D-042',
  },
];

export default function GridSample() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 200, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        columns={[
          { field: 'username', hideable: false },
          { field: 'age' },
          { field: 'desk' },
        ]}
        rows={rows}
        slots={{
          toolbar: GridToolbar,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then  I apply it with Api data, the data not rendered, but the recordset/rows count populated correctly
Searching solution mostly suggest to set auto height props or container height, but still not working.

Am I missing something here?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


export default function VisibleColumnsBasicExample() {

const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

const endpoint = 'http://localhost:3500/catalog'

const getData = async () => {
    await axios.get(endpoint).then((response) => {
        const data = response.data
        setProducts(data)
        console.log(data)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, [])

const rows = products

return (
    <div style={{ height: 200, width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGrid
            columns={[
                { field: 'Model Code', hideable: false },
                { field: 'Model Description' },
                { field: 'Price' },
                { field: 'Status' },
                { field: 'Start Date' },
                { field: 'End Date' },
            ]}

            rows={rows}
            slots={{
                toolbar: GridToolbar,
            }}

            getRowId={
                (row) => row.modelCode
            }
        />
    </div>
   );
   }
```

On the other hand, when I used @mui/material/Table code below, data from the same Api rendered corretly

EDIT : adding capture of result

@pawel

here is the result

[const rows = {products}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUg5a.png)

[const rows = products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU83I.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this `const rows = products` might shake things up. Variables aren't persistent between react refresh. Try to do `rows={products}`. If it won't help, please send screenshot of data format you get from api, it would give some more context.

Comment: look at editted question above

Answer (score 0):

Solved :
my bad, I assume this columns as just column header name, but actually it is refer to the each field table, so I adjust this field as is in database field

```
columns={[
                { field: 'modelCode', hideable: false },
                { field: 'modelDesc' },
                { field: 'price' },
                { field: 'status' },
                { field: 'startDate' },
                { field: 'endDate' },
            ]}
```